# Upload Button in meta box not opening library

Tags: uploads, metabox

First, thank you for your help.

I have created a custom template, added two metaboxes in Pages using a 'Page_Fiche_Metier.php' template. 
One meta box is to upload an image. But the Upload Button is not opening the media library, although I have added the jQuery script.

```
Here is the code for the meta-boxes.php

    <?php

function prfx_custom_meta(){
  global $post;
    if ( 'page_fiche_metier.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
    add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta', __( 'Vidéo Présentation Bas de Page', 'prfx-textdomain' ), 'prfx_meta_callback', 'page' );
  }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );


function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
    $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="meta-text" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Titre', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="meta-text" id="meta-text" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-text'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['meta-text'][0]; ?>" />
    </p>


      <p>
        <label for="meta-url" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'URL', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="meta-url" id="meta-url" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-url'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['meta-url'][0]; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="meta-image" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example File Upload', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="meta-image" id="meta-image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-image'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta[
        'meta-image'][0]; ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Choisir un fichier', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>" />
    </p>

    <?php
}


function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }


    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) );
    }



    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-url' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-url', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-url' ] ) );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-image', $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );


function prfx_image_enqueue() {
    global $typenow;
    if( $typenow == 'post' ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();

        // Registers and enqueues the required javascript.
        wp_register_script( 'meta-box-image', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'meta-box-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'meta-box-image', 'meta_image',
            array(
                'title' => __( 'Choose or Upload an Image', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
                'button' => __( 'Use this image', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-box-image' );
    }
}
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prfx_image_enqueue' );
```

And the code for js:

```
/*
 * Attaches the image uploader to the input field
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
    var meta_image_frame;

    // Runs when the image button is clicked.
    $('#meta-image-button').click(function(e){

        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault();

        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if ( meta_image_frame ) {
            meta_image_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: meta_image.title,
            button: { text:  meta_image.button },
            library: { type: 'image' }
        });

        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            $('#meta-image').val(media_attachment.url);
        });

        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you've added the meta box for pages:

> I have created a custom template, added two metaboxes in Pages using a
>   'Page_Fiche_Metier.php' template.

However, in `prfx_image_enqueue()`, the code only runs if the post type is `post`. Changing `prfx_image_enqueue()` so that it checks for the `page` post type will fix the issue.

```
function prfx_image_enqueue() {
    global $typenow;
    if ( $typenow == 'page' ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();

        // Registers and enqueues the required javascript.
        wp_register_script( 'meta-box-image', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'meta-box-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'meta-box-image', 'meta_image',
                array(
                        'title' => __( 'Choose or Upload an Image', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
                        'button' => __( 'Use this image', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
                )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-box-image' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prfx_image_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. 
I found the issue. 
The path "plugin_dir_url( **FILE** ) . 'meta-box-image.js' " was not the correct one. I just changed to the correct directory! 
Best